# Favourite Joomla Template hide arrows

Tags: templates, joomla, arrows

I am building a web site using Favourite Joompla template. 
http://favthemes.com/tutorials-developers

I also use videobox extension insert videos and image gallery for images

The problem is that i cannot seem to be able to remove the arrows that appear near the boxes of the above extensions. Keep in mind that these arrows appear only when i apply Favourite template. How can i remove them ?

You can check them below

[image: http://i59.tinypic.com/2qi791u.png]

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). I recommend you asking your future [tag:joomla]-related questions there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locate the container that these lists belong to and then go to template.css and add on the bottom, i.e.:

```
.item ul li:before {display:none;}
```

If you want to make it specific for a module, add a class to the module or use the module position ID and make it like:

```
#fav-sidebar2 ul li:before {display:none;}
.moduleclass ul li:before {display:none;}
```